Adding CSS class to element with PHP for what time of day it is
Okay, so I asked this question before, but I really did a terrible job explaining myself & may have even annoyed some folks. For that, I am sorry. So let me explain the issue better.
I have a header/hero div inside my php file which requires selecting between one of six classes per the current time of day in New York, EST time. The classes & times of day in which I would like them based on are as follows.
12:00am - 5:00am: tod__twilight
5:00am - 8:00am: tod__sunrise
8:00am - 12:00pm: tod__morning
12:00pm - 5:00pm: tod__afternoon
5:00pm - 8:00pm: tod_sunset
8:00pm - 12:00am: tod__night
The site I'm working on is a wordpress site so I would strongly prefer the code to be PHP based, not Javascript.
This is the basic markup I have:
$tod_class = '';
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$current_date = date('H:i:s');
php code to select time of day which does not work goes here
<div class="bg__color w-100vw h-100vh--40 absolute top-0 left-0 z-1 <?php echo $tod_class; ?>"></div>

Again, I apologize for being far to vague before, the class I want to add is indeed a CSS class which I would be applying to the "bg__color" div. Thank you all in advance

You can simply check the time of day using if statements, and set $tod_class accordingly.
If you use intval(date('H')), this will return hour component of the datetime, which seems to be all you need.
For example:
<?php 
$tod_class = '';
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$current_hour = intval(date('H')); // Get the hour in 24-hour time
if ($current_hour < 5) {
    $tod_class = 'tod_twilight';
} else if ($current_hour < 8) {
    $tod_class = 'tod_sunrise';
} else if ($current_hour < 12) {
    $tod_class = 'tod_morning';
} else if ($current_hour < 17) {
    $tod_class = 'tod_afternoon';
} else if ($current_hour < 20) {
    $tod_class = 'tod_sunset';
} else {
    $tod_class = 'tod_night';
}
?>
<div class="bg__color w-100vw h-100vh--40 absolute top-0 left-0 z-1 <?php echo $tod_class; ?>">
    test
</div>

Hope this helps.
